# set_rules() not co-operating

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

This is something wack, when set_rules is told to look for `current_password` it doesn't work yet when it's told to look for `current-password` it does.

```
<input type="password" name="current_password" id="current_password" value=""/>
```

Note that both name and id have an underscore.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('current_password', 'Password', 'required|callback_check_password['.$user_id.']');
//This gives me
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.
```

The above rule wont work, yet if I change it too `set_rules('current-password'` it starts shows the error message.

Printing error messages with `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>`

Doing a dump of post shows `array(1) { ["current_password"]=> string(4) "test" }`

Comment: I don't know if the callback is good formatted, I think it should be `callback_check_password` instead of `callback_check_password['.$user_id.']`

Comment: I'm passing in another param, it's allowed.

Comment: How do you set the field message in your callback function?

Comment: Yeah looks like that was the problem, I was setting a message in the callback. So went ahead and set one and it starts working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't setting an error message in the callback function

```
function check_password($password, $user_id){
    $check = $this->Usermodel->check_password($password, $user_id);
    if($check){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_password', 'Incorrect password');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```